# Padding is invalid and cannot be removed while sending push event to my application

Tags: docusignapi

We are using Docusign Connect to leverage the push functionality. This feature is great and we are no more worried of reaching REST call limits.

But while checking connect logs on DocuSign console- We found failure entry which is failing because of below error:

```
9/16/2013 6:50:23 AM  Connect send to: https://myURL.com/EventListener
9/16/2013 6:50:23 AM  Envelope Data (documents were included):
9/16/2013 6:50:23 AM  Error: Exception in EnvelopeIntegration.RunIntegration: <EnvelopeID> :: https://myURL.com/EventListener :: Error - Exception decrypting. Padding is invalid and cannot be removed. Original Exception: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.
```

Looks like this is some internal exception at Docusign. Can someone help us to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug on DocuSign's side.  It's newly introduced which means it most likely came from the latest release.  Will post an update here once resolved, thanks for your patience.

DocuSign Team